# Zend_Db_Table Relationships and Zend_Paginator

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, zend-paginator

is there a way, hot to apply paginator limit on select, which I send to findDependentRowset function? for example:

```
$select = $row->select();
$select->order('item_name');    
$row->findDependentRowset($table, null, $select)
```

thank's

Answer (score 1):

You need just add limit to your select passed to findDependentRowset. 
It will look like this:

```
$select = $row->select()->limit($itemCountPerPage,$offset);
$select->order('item_name');    
$row->findDependentRowset($table, null, $select);
```

Answer (score 0):

this looks good, but paginator will don't have information about all rows count. I found solution to override Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect and set function

```
public function getItems($offset, $itemCountPerPage)
{
   $this->_select->limit($itemCountPerPage, $offset);
   return $this->_select;
}
```

this will return select with applied limit and I can use Paginator with its whole funcionality